# springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui with Spring Boot 3 results in Uncaught SyntaxError

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

When trying to load http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html, I will receive an error console with this output:

```
swagger-ui-bundle.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (at swagger-ui-bundle.js:2:537471)
swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (at swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js:2:147026)
swagger-initializer.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: SwaggerUIBundle is not defined
    at window.onload (swagger-initializer.js:5:3)
window.onload @ swagger-initializer.js:5
load (async)
(anonymous) @ swagger-initializer.js:1
```

Anybody an idea?

my pom.xml

```
 <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        **<version>3.1.6</version>**
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
      
        <!-- SWAGGER -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            **<version>2.0.0</version>**
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I tried to load other versions, but nothing seems to help. Trying to change the plugins as I suspected that this could be a problem

Answer (score 0):

try using this version for testing :

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.11</version> <!--- old version from 2021 -->
    </dependency>
```

also make sure your application.properties is properiate  :

```
## Swagger-ui & Documentation
springdoc.api-docs.enabled=true
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui.html
springdoc.api-docs.path=/api-docs
springdoc.swagger-ui.enabled=true
springdoc.swagger-ui.operationsSorter=method
springdoc.swagger-ui.tryItOutEnabled=true
springdoc.swagger-ui.filter=false
springdoc.swagger-ui.tagsSorter=alpha
springdoc.swagger-ui.validatorUrl=none
springdoc.swagger-ui.defaultModelRendering=model
springdoc.swagger-ui.docExpansion=full
```